# data synchronization among multiple devices

Tags: mysql, oracle, database-design, synchronization, amazon-cognito

There is my website this is an accounting software. now i am willing to create mobile application for my website in android windows and ios.

And i want to synchronize data properly across all devices.

currently i am doing testing with aws cognito. but I have some issues with this.

Is there any other thing which full fill my requirement.
main thing is that i dnt want to develop synchronization logic in my software i want to use any service which provide this facility.

you can go through this link and find what i want
http://aws.amazon.com/cognito/

Comment: What issues are facing with cognito?

Comment: 1. it's processing is slow. 2. it is using no sql dynamodb and It has so many limitations. I can not query properly. If i want to fetch only one field then it is not possible with that I have to fetch whole document.

Answer (score 2):

Since your application is web-based, you must have a database attached to your application's web site.

Your mobile applications should not store large amounts of data if at all possible.  Instead, your applications should retrieve and modify data in the website's database through RESTful web APIs.

This eliminates the need for data synchronization because all data is stored in a single repository.